# How can i store all simulation results using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I'm running a simulation algorithm for example 500 runs, (note: the result is matrix) , my question is: How can i store all the results "the 500 matrix" ? i want first matrix,then the second after the first etc. i will have a bigger matrix 500 matrix vertically, Is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your result matrix `Mcurrent`

If you want to save it you can say `save Mcurrent`

However suppose you have a result matrix `Mcurrent` and you want to attach the new results `Mnew` to it you can do

```
Mcurrent = [Mcurrent Mnew]
```

or

```
Mcurrent = [Mcurrent; Mnew]
```

depending on the size of `Mnew`.

Answer (score 0):

If the results are large you might want to save them in their own file and post process later.  For something like CFD that would be the norm (save each as its own and write a script to process the results on each file).